# Probability Flux reduced to imaginary part?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, probability

I'm looking at Sakurai, page 400.
The probabilityflux (**j**) can be reduced to the imaginary part of the first part of **j**. Can somebody explain this?

**j**(**x**,t) $=-\frac{i\hbar}{2m}[\psi^*\nabla\psi-(\nabla\psi^*)\psi]$
$=\frac{\hbar}{m}Im(\psi^*\nabla\psi)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: A general complex number $z$ can be written as
\begin{align}
z = a + i b
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b$ are real. Now consider the complex conjugate of $z$.(i.e. $\overline{z}$)
\begin{align}
\overline{z} = a - ib
\end{align}

As a result, adding and subtracting the above two equations gives the following relations.
\begin{align}
z + \overline{z} \; = \; 2a &\implies \mathrm{Re}(z) \equiv a = \frac{z + \overline{z}}{2} \\
z -\overline{z} \; = \; 2ib &\implies \mathrm{Im}(z) \equiv b = \frac{z - \overline{z}}{2i}
\end{align}